# Javascript/jQuery --> How to make loop so that after the last testimonial /li/ the whole ul will repeat again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

How to make loop so that after the last testimonial /li/ the whole ul will repeat again (so after the last slide there will be first slide again)?

This is my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t2zwo0fr/14/

This is the function which does interval, I want to enhance it with loop so that after the last testimonial /li/ there whole ul will repeat:

```
function blink() {
    if (active || slideIndex >= slideCount - 1) {
        return;
    }
    slideIndex++;
    active = true;
    $('ul').animate(
        {'left': $('ul').position().left-szer1slidu},
        3000,
        function() {
            { active = false; }
        }
    );  
}
setInterval(blink,1000);
```

Comment: What's that `{ active = false; }` supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to disable clicks on next/prev arrows while the animation is active

Comment: Maybe remove the extra `{}`

Comment: While you didn't ask for a library, I have been using this one and it's pretty good: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0):

Well, when the animation reaches the third `li`, I would use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to move the first `li` to the last position and every time the "previous" animation is called, I'd [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) the other way around.. but that's without jQuery. :p

Also, don't forget to update the position of the `ul` to still show the current `li`.